# Tableview loading more than 50 images Received memory warning

Tags: ios, uitableview, didreceivememorywarning

This is my cell data

```
for (int s=0; s<[arrayForPhotosData1 count]; s++) {
    PhotoCell *cell=[[PhotoCell alloc] init];
    cell.imgPhoto.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    cell.imgPhoto.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
    cell.imgPhoto.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    cell.imgPhoto.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
    cell.imgPhoto.clipsToBounds = NO;
    if([[arrayForPhotosData1 objectAtIndex:s] valueForKey:@"resolution_280_280"]!=NULL)
    {
        [cell.imgPhoto loadImage:[[arrayForPhotosData1 objectAtIndex:s] valueForKey:@"resolution_280_280"]];

    }
    [cell.ImgProfile loadImage:[[arrayForPhotosData1 objectAtIndex:s] valueForKey:@"profile_picture"]];
    [cell.lblUserName setText:[[arrayForPhotosData1 objectAtIndex:s] valueForKey:@"caption"]];
    [cell.lblForTime setText:[[arrayForPhotosData1 objectAtIndex:s] valueForKey:@"created_time"]];
    [cell.lblFullName setText:[[arrayForPhotosData1 objectAtIndex:s] valueForKey:@"Name" ]];
    [cell.btnForLike addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(addlikes:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.btnForLike  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.btnForFavourite addTarget:self
                             action:@selector(addFavourite:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.btnForFavourite.tag=[[[arrayForPhotosData1  objectAtIndex:s]valueForKey:@"mediaid"] intValue];
    cell.btnForComment.tag=[[[arrayForPhotosData1  objectAtIndex:s]valueForKey:@"mediaid"] intValue];
    [cell.btnForComment addTarget:self action:@selector(addcomen:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.imgPhoto.tag=[[[arrayForPhotosData1  objectAtIndex:s]valueForKey:@"mediaid"] intValue];
    [cell.imgPhoto addTarget:self action:@selector(addcoments:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.btnForLike.tag=s;

    [cell.btnForLikeText setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Me gusta",[[arrayForPhotosData1 objectAtIndex:s] valueForKey:@"Totallikes"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell.btnForCommentText setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Commentarios",[[arrayForPhotosData1 objectAtIndex:s] valueForKey:@"TotalComment"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell.btnForLikeText addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(addlikes:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.btnForLikeText.tag=s;
    cell.btnForCommentText.tag=s;
    cell.btnForFavouritetext.tag=s;
    [cell.btnForFavouritetext addTarget:self
                                 action:@selector(addFavourite:)
                       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btnForCommentText addTarget:self action:@selector(addcomen:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    if([[[arrayForPhotosData1 objectAtIndex:s] valueForKey:@"FavoriteIsActive"] isEqualToString:@"true"])
    {

        [cell.btnForFavouritetext setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",@"Favoritos"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [cell.btnForFavouritetext setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",@"Favoritos"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [arrayForCell addObject:cell];
}

[tableViewForPhotos reloadData];
```

and this is my displaying data in cell

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier1 = @"TableItem1";

PhotoCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier1];

if (cell1 == nil) {
    cell1 = [[PhotoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier1];
}

if ([arrayForCell count]>0) {
    cell1= [arrayForCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];

    cell1.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell1;
}
```

After loading 50 images, app is getting Received memory warning.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to check if **cell1** is nil. If you registered **[PhotoCell class]**, then it's never going to be **nil**.

I believe you're receiving a memory warning because you're not reusing cells.

Here:

```
cell1= [arrayForCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
```

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Matteo Pacini In indexpath 0 I created another cell thats why I am Using [indexpath.row-1]

Comment: Issue is: you're dequeuing a reusable cell (stored in **cell1**), and then you're discarding it when control reaches this line `cell1= [arrayForCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1]`

Comment: So what is the solution

Comment: can u please tell me solution I am struggling 5 days

Comment: The way you create cell is totally wrong. You should dequeue them inside **cellForRowAtIndexPath**. In MVC paradigm, you should use an array of models (e.g. data to populate your cells) instead of an array of cells.

Comment: I know that but when I am scrolloing images are interchanged thats why  i am using like this